# Get Web Service Context Listner in JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, glassfish-3

When Web Service in loaded for the first time i need it to send a message(it contains the url to access this service) to one of my installed web applications. This web application is keeping track of alive web services. How can i achieve this?

May this is not the right way to do it...but i need a simplistic approach.

Can i get access Web Service Context Listner? If its the right way to go...

My environment is JAX-WS 2.2, Javaee1.6, Glassfish 3.1.

Comment: I am not thinking of using UDDI/ebXML right now...i need a simple web applcaition that justs shows the web services initialized and their urls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have thought about it before putting the question about the probable answer. Here is the answer may be already many people know it.

I am using @Resource annotation on instance of WebServiceContext in my Web Service class.